# Seeking GIS datasets that has the degree, minutes and seconds world longitude and latitude

Tags: data-request, download

I am seeking a GIS datasets that has the longitude and latitude that I really need badly that has the degrees, minutes  and seconds .... I am aware that there is 1 degree, 5 degree, 30 degree and 45 degrees.... I do not want them...

Where do I find them ? I have looked around on the internet and didn't find it....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of any such existing datasets, but you can make your own layer in either QGIS or Arc.  Search for "create fishnets" in GIS Stack Exchange.  BTW, a worldwide layer at your granularity will be immense, approaching 4 billion(!) polygons, which probably explains why you didn't find one. You may want to create such a layer at a regional scale instead.

Comment: Thank you for the explain ! Now I understand why ....wow... Okay...I'll do that what you are suggesting...